# 400 error white Java Post using application/x-www-form-urlencoded in body

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-400

```
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String response = "";
        String urlParameters = "";
try {
        URL obj = new URL("url");
         urlParameters = "grant_type=client_credentials";
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setRequestProperty("authorization", "Basic value");

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(urlParameters);

        // For POST only - START
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + os);
        System.out.println("Response Code================================================================================================================ : " + responseCode);

     in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;



    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response = inputLine;
    }
    }
 finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();

        }
    }   }
```

I am using this API to get TOKEN.But getting 400 in all cases.

As per the document[API request details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAjHu.png)

Please help to solve the issue.

I think its an issue with adding the body part ,so I appended the body part into URL,But it also failed.

For this code I got error:sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837711/httpurlconnection-failing-on-post-with-http-400/69837712#69837712

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use Apache HTTP Client library instead of the HttpURLConnection. For example of the HTTP Client see https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-4-basic-authentication

Comment: I agree, you should use a HTTP client library

Comment: Alternative for the Apache HTTP Client is to use the http client in Java 11, see for instance https://mkyong.com/java/java-11-httpclient-examples/

Comment: Any way to use HttpURLConnection .I am new to all these

Comment: Any help to edit this code and fix the issue@LazarPetrovic @R.Groote

Comment: I think its an issue with the body.

Comment: I got this error in log sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection